# Imports in multi-file Coq projects

Tags: coq

I have the following project structure:

```
theories
  |
  *--> defn.v
  |
  *--> thm.v
```

'defn.v' has some definitions and compiles perfectly with coqc command. However, I want to import definitions from 'defn.v' into 'thm.v'. Hence I put something like 'Require Import defn.v.' in 'thm.v'. Is there a way to compile 'thm.v' without first compiling 'defn.v' (or manually traversing this dependency). Besides this, I want to load 'defn.v' while using coqtop. I'm not able to load 'defn.v' even after being able to compile it.

I read about _CoqProject, but I was not able to use it. I read about -R, -Q arguments too. Therefore, I first compiled 'defn.v' using:

```
coqc -Q . "" defn.v
```

After that I ran coqtop in the same directory and did something like:

```
Add LoadPath "<absolute-path-to-theories-directory>" as theories.
From theories Require Import defn.

(* This fails with message: The file /home/*****************/theories/defn.vo contains library defn and not library theories.defn. *)
```

I have a specific requirement where I will not be able to pass any commandline argument(s) to coqtop, I want to know how to load 'defn.v' in coqtop while using something like "Add LoadPath".

Comment: HI @amit9oct, try to mimic this _CoqProject (https://github.com/mukeshtiwari/Dlog-zkp/blob/main/_CoqProject) and see if it works. If you are working with Emacs, open the whole directory in which _CoqProject reside. Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of coq are you using?

```
coqc defn.v
```

Then inside `coqtop`

```
Require defn.
```

should work.

If you want to use the `-Q` option, this gives

```
coqc -Q . mylib defn.v
```

Then inside `coqtop`

```
From mylib Require defn.
```